# using jquery on definition list (dl)

Tags: jquery, html

Because I need to horizontally list the items, I have several dl, each contains an image

> ```
> <dl class="hints" id="hint0">
>   <dt><img ...></dt>
>   <dd>a</dd>
> </dl>
> <dl class="hints" id="hint1">
>   <dt><img ...></dt>
>   <dd>b</dd>
> </dl>
> <dl class="hints" id="hint2">
>   <dt><img ...></dt>
>   <dd>c</dd>
> </dl>
> ```

I want to use jquery to do something when click on each image. How to get the object of the dl/dt/img? Currently, "$('dl.hints dt').click(function()..." doesn't work.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: not a formal answer, but if I were you, I'd try to add a class to the images, so you are not so tied up to the current DOM, also, your selector is wrong, it should be $("dl.hints dt img")

Comment: [Works fine for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/zFUv3/) Any reason to have multiple lists instead of a list with multiple entries? (Oh, I was attaching the click to the `<dt>` not the image, as your selector implied.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/ZxzWN/

Comment: @DaveNewton I need to horizontally list the items, and it seems only this way can work. Please let me know if you have any idea to use one single <dl> to list them all horizontally.

Comment: @xuc [Horizontal def list](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/314-How-to-make-a-horizontal-definition-list-dl-dd-dt-) may work.

Comment: @DaveNewton In this example, dd is also horizontal, but I want dd under dt.

Comment: @xuc I'm not convinced I'd use a def. list for this, but ok.

Comment: $('.hints dt img').live('click',function(){
  alert('Works.') 
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned if you want to do some action when i click on image inside dt" of "hints" class.. Then try the below code...

```
$('.hints dt img').live('click',function()
{
  alert('This works');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the jQuery ready state.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.hints dt img').click(function()
{
  alert('OK');
});
}):
```